# approximate the integral of sin(t)/t from 0 to 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

The problem asks me to use my 7th degree maclaurin approximation (x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!) to approximate (sin(t)/t)dt. I have no clue how to go about this I know that the integral of sin(t) from 0 to 1 is equal to the integral of the maclaurin polynomial from 0 to 1. But I don't know what to do with the extra 1/t.

Comment: Divide the Maclaurin polynomial by $t$?

Comment: The integral of $\sin t$ from $0$ to $1$ is only *approximately* equal to the integral of the Maclaurin polynomial from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You have that $$\sin(t)\approx t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}-\frac{t^7}{7!}$$ so: $$\frac{\sin (t)}{t}\approx 1-\frac{t^2}{3!}+\frac{t^4}{5!}-\frac{t^6}{7!}$$

Comment: oh okay that's easier than I thought, thank you so much! So then I would just integrate 1-t^2/6 right?

Comment: The question asks you to use the $7$th degree approximation, no? Recall that since the RHS is an *approximation* of the LHS, the integral of the RHS is an approximation of the integral of the LHS as well.

Comment: So in question A it asks for me to make a 7th degree polynomial. Question B says to use that answer to approximate the integral. So yeah I guess I should be using the whole polynomial. So then id integrate 1−t^2/3!+t^4/5!−t^6/7! from 0-1 right ?

Comment: Exactly that, just simple integration of a polynomial.

Comment: Awesome thank you!